Set the key type in the object based on the contents of the array
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
/** @typedef ??????? KeyType`*/ //is important that the type is based on the values from the keys
/** @type {{[key: KeyType]?: number}} */
const obj = {};
for(const k of keys){
  obj[k] = Math.random(); // good
}
obj['foo'] = 3; // IDE should show warning, but it doesn't care

I've tried
/** @enum {string} */
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
/** @type {{[key: keys]?: number}} */
// ...

but then it just determines that the type is string, but it is not strict with the value

You can do something like this:
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'] as const;
type Keys = typeof keys[number];
const obj: Record<Keys, any> = {} as Record<Keys, any>;
obj['foo'] = 3; // error
obj['x'] = 3; // ok


Yes, but only using JSDoc
